# Small footprint embedded Java SQL database

Tags: java, sql, database

I'm looking for an embedded SQL database for Java, with a small footprint. Something like SQLite, but it should be pure Java. So far I've seen HSQLDB, H2 and Apache Derby, but they're not what could be called small footprint. Ideally, the database I'm looking for would be embeddable in a J2ME application.

Is there something like this?

Comment: @MJB, just what I said in the question: "ideally, the database I'm looking for would be embeddable in a J2ME application".

Comment: I don't think that you will find a good SQL J2ME database. AFAIR there is no RandomAccessFile available in J2ME (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795327/file-random-access-in-j2me ) - without this a database implementation is nearly impossible because you have to reopen it very very often and a lot of J2ME file system implementations have problems with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try http://www.jepstone.net/tinySQL/.

Pros:

- It is small (93k!)
- It is embeddable
- It uses DBF or text files files to store data, so they are easy to read.

Cons:

- It is an old unmaintained project
- It is **not** designed to work in j2me, but since it can work in JDK 1.1.8 it won't be hard to make it work in j2me. Of course you will have to change some code from using RandomAccessFile to FileConnection and stuff like that, but at least you wont need to mess with generics related code.
- It is not very fast, because it does not use indexes, so you need to try and see if it is fits yuor needs
- It is not feature complete, just gives you a small subset of SQL

Answer (score 15):

Take a look at [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) or [H2DB](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)

or possibly a light key value based database like [jdbm2](http://code.google.com/p/jdbm2/)

Comment: The creator of HSQLDB and H2, Thomas Mueller, [states](http://www.infoq.com/news/h2-released) that H2 is faster than HSQLDB for most operations and is architecturally superior. You should probably go with H2 instead of HSQLDB.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is an Apache project for that called [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/).

Answer (score 2):

You can also look at:

- Floggy - http://floggy.sourceforge.net/
- Perts Lite - http://www.mcobject.com/j2me_database/
- J2MEMicroDB - http://morfeo.upc.es/crom/mod/wiki/view.php?id=16&page=Qu%E8+%E9s+J2MELSDATALIB&gid=0&uid=0
- HandyDB - http://sourceforge.net/projects/rms-db-class/
- MicroDB - http://sourceforge.net/projects/microdb/
- OpenBaseMovil - http://www.openbasemovil.org/2007/11/26/openbasemovil-portable-j2me-database-applications/

This list is something I just found on the internet (http://www.coderanch.com/t/230853/JME/Mobile/List-Database-ME) and some of the listed products seems abandoned, but I thought that maybe it can be helpful...